# Disable Windows Task Scheduler job locally if scheduled task is enabled and running on a remote server

Tags: batch, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to disable a Windows Task Scheduler job on local system using a batch file but only if it is already enabled and running on a remote system. Obviously the "`[servername]`" will be replaced by an actual remote server name.

It is working perfect for Task Scheduler jobs without spaces in the task name. However, the below code snippet is not working for task names that contain a space within the job names such as ("Test Sample Job").

### Batch File

```
for /f "tokens=1" %%j in ('schtasks /Query /S [servername] /TN "Test Sample Job" /NH ^| findstr "Ready ^| Running"') do schtasks /Change /Disable /TN "%%j"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If looks like you need to plan for the number of spaces between the job name(s) 
 you'll use this logic for, and then adjust the `tokens` and `variables` accordingly.

For the "**Test Sample Job**" in particular use:

```
for /f "tokens=1-9" %%j in ('schtasks /Query /S [servername] /TN "Test Sample Job" /NH ^| findstr "Ready ^| Running"') do schtasks /Change /Disable /TN "%%j %%k %%l"
```

> **Note:** *This would not work for job names without spaces so you'll need a script per the job names with and without spaces. You'll need
>   to have a separate script for job names with 2 spaces, 3 spaces, 4
>   spaces, and so on so you may need to standardize the job naming better
>   or plan scripts accordingly.*

---

### Further Resources

- `FOR /?`

  > ```
  >     tokens=x,y,m-n  - specifies which tokens from each line are to
  >                       be passed to the for body for each iteration.
  >                       This will cause additional variable names to
  >                       be allocated.  The m-n form is a range,
  >                       specifying the mth through the nth tokens.  If
  >                       the last character in the tokens= string is an
  >                       asterisk, then an additional variable is
  >                       allocated and receives the remaining text on
  >                       the line after the last token parsed.
  >
  >     Some examples might help:
  >
  >   FOR /F "eol=; tokens=2,3* delims=, " %i in (myfile.txt) do @echo %i %j %k
  >
  >     would parse each line in myfile.txt, ignoring lines that begin with
  >     a semicolon, passing the 2nd and 3rd token from each line to the for
  >     body, with tokens delimited by commas and/or spaces.  Notice the for
  >     body statements reference %i to get the 2nd token, %j to get the
  >     3rd token, and %k to get all remaining tokens after the 3rd.  For
  >     file names that contain spaces, you need to quote the filenames with
  >     double quotes.  In order to use double quotes in this manner, you also
  >     need to use the usebackq option, otherwise the double quotes will be
  >     interpreted as defining a literal string to parse.
  >
  >
  >     %i is explicitly declared in the for statement and the %j and %k
  >     are implicitly declared via the tokens= option.  You can specify up
  >     to 26 tokens via the tokens= line, provided it does not cause an
  >     attempt to declare a variable higher than the letter 'z' or 'Z'.
  >     Remember, FOR variables are single-letter, case sensitive, global,
  >     and you can't have more than 52 total active at any one time.
  > ```